# How do I get my code to work?

Tags: c#

I have a one assignment

I have to make one dimension array with 20 numbers - first 10 numbers are from 1 do 10. others 10 numbers I have to get in method called Dopolni - where I have to sum together array with one another like - p11 = p0+p1, p12 = p1+p2, p14 = p2+p3 and so on - I dont know how to arrange it to get those other 10 numbers - help please

my code till now is

```
static void Dopolni(int[] p)
{
    for (int i = 11; i < 20; i++)
    {
        p[i] = p[i] + 1;
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] p = new int[20];

    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if (i <= 10)
        {
            p[i] += i;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", p[i]);
    }
    Dopolni(p);
    Console.WriteLine(p);
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

All numbers I have to write out in main window. Hope someone can help out

Comment: your description of dopolni is unclear

Comment: What error are you seeing (I can guess, but you should consider what the error message says)

Comment: there is no error its just now working -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indices of the first 10 numbers range from 0 to 9, the others from 10 to 19. But since you always sum two consecutive numbers, you will only get 9 sums! In order to get 10 sums, you could start by summing 0 with p[0]:

```
int previous = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    p[i + 10] = previous + p[i];
    previous = p[i];
}
```

Comment: its working in that code - but still I should made Console.WriteLine(p) in main and not in both methods

Comment: static void Dopolni(int[] p)
        {
            for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++)
            {
                p[i] = p[i - 10] + p[i - 9];
                Console.WriteLine("p[{0}] = {1}", i, p[i]);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] p = new int[20];

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                    p[i] = i + 1;
                Console.WriteLine("p[{0}] = {1}", i, p[i]);
            }
            Dopolni(p);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

Comment: The problem with your method is that the first sum is placed in `p[10]`, but the last sum (with i = 19) is `p[19] = p[9] + p[10]`. So `p[19]` will be `p[9] + p[0] + p[1]` because `p[10]` is `p[0] + p[1]`! I try to avoid this by starting with `p[-1] + p[0]`. Because `p[-1]` does not exist, I use the variable `previous`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have it in a function? Its really quite simple...

Notice I use 'out int[]', thats what your missing in your code. Out specifies you want in/out param, not just in ;)

```
static void Main()
{
    int[] p = new int[20];

    // First 10 numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        p[i] = i + 1;

    Dolpini(out p);

    foreach (int m in p)
        Console.WriteLine(m);
}

static void Dolpini(out int[] numbers)
{
    // Next 10 numbers
    for (int k = 10; k < 20; k++)
        p[k] = p[k-10] + p[k-9];
}
```

Comment: and have all 20 numbers written out in main again

Comment: This will overwrite the sum in p[10] when k is 19! I think that the question is not clear on this point.

Comment: I somehow rewritten my code but I still am not able to write the whole p[i] in main method

Comment: What do you mean not able to write the whole p[i]? What does it output?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main()
{
  int[] p = new int[20];
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    p[i] = i + 1;
    ¨
    Console.WriteLine(p[i]);

  }

  Dopolni(p);

}

static void Dopolni(int[] p)
{
  for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++)
  {
    p[i] = p[i - 10] + p[i - 9];
    Console.WriteLine(p[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like trouble:

> ```
> int[] p = new int[20];
> Console.WriteLine(p);
> ```

What you want is to loop through `p` and print each element, not rely on the array implementation of `ToString()`.

Try:

```
foreach (var n in p)
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```